# Use existing relation or create a new one

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this form which relates to an object of class Film, which has a Director relation, and I would like to have a choice between selecting an existing director or creating a new one.
The first choice is easy :

```
class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('director');
    }
}
```

The second choice is a quite easy too :

```
class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('director', new DirectorType());
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to reconcile the two solutions.
I tried this:

```
class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    { 
        $builder->add('director')->add('director2', new DirectorType());
    }
}
```

but of course, it does not work because my entity has no corresponding field, and I get the following error :

> Neither property "director_2" nor method "getDirector2()" nor method
>   "isDirector2()" exists in class "Uc\LegalBundle\Entity\Film"

I think I should perhaps create a new class named `DirectorChoiceType`, for instance, but it seems a bit too much for this. Isn't there a simpler way to go?

Mockup of what I want to achieve :
[image]

Comment: @hakre: sorry, I misstyped, I meant director, not directory.

Comment: @gregOire: I thought so but miss-typed as well.

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to do? What is the actual decision (in simple words) to create a new director or to re-use an existing director?

Comment: The user must have the choice between these two solution, I'm going to add a mockup very soon so that this is clear.

Comment: @gregOire: Then let the user decide and act upon. What is your problem? Might be only one if.

Comment: The problem is : how can I generate such a field using the `buildForm` method?

Comment: Symfony2 AFAIK does not do it this way for you automatically. You need to code that on your own by adding some code that reflects the users decision within your implementation while re-using symfony2 forms components. That easy it is. Please show your code and explain into which *concrete* problem you did run, e.g. creating a new Directory everytime while assigning an existing one or similar.

Comment: @hakre: My problem is not within the `create` action, but within the `new` (I'm not sure I'm getting your last sentence, which makes me feel like you think the problem is when creating the objects), I added the exception I'm getting and some more code.

Comment: You either have a form you edit an existing object, or you have a form to create a new one. Separate it from each other *or* just provide some form fields you can base your decision on. Then you can add/update the objects in your controller with your own logic. Should work.

Comment: I am going to base the decision on the emptyness of the combo box, no need for extra fields. The question is "how can I display such a composite widget?", and I agree, it should definitely work.

Comment: Composite Widget? You might just want to create a new form element that is a compound of many others.

Comment: Sounds good, but is [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) all the non-documentation there is about it? Or are there other pages that might not help me achieve this? :P

Comment: Ah okay, you're after that missing link. Got it. Well, in this case the code are the docs. Checkout the standard elements from source. Add one on your own (you can extend from the base classes). Also the docs about how elements get rendered in the main form docs are interesting in this context.

Comment: @hakre: I guess the project is still very young. I'll post an answer when I'm done. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: Yeah symfony2 is gold since about a month or so? And I find the docs quite useful already now. You can contribute to the documentation as well, it's a free software project. Let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// form
class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    { 
        $builder
            ->add('new_director_fn')
            ->add('new_director_ln')
            ->add('director', null, array(
                'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
                'required' => false
            ));
    }
}

// entity
class Film
{

    // not mapped
    private $new_director_fn;

    // not mapped
    private $new_director_ln;

    // orm relation
    private $director;
    }
}


// controller
class FilmController
{

    public function createAction()
    {

        //...

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if ( $film->director === null && ($film->new_director_fn && $film->new_director_ln) )
            {
                $director = new Director();
                $director->setFirstName($film->new_director_fn);
                $director->setLastName($film->new_director_ln);
                $em->persist($director);
                $film->setDirector($director);
            }
            $em->persist($film);
            $em->flush();
        }

        //...

    }
}
```

Comment: sounds good! I won't be able to test your solution for a long time, but if it works, I'll accept your answer then. Thanks and +1.